# Convert a string from ISO-8859-2 to UTF-8 in the Dart language

Tags: dart

I would like to convert a string from the ISO-8859-2 character set to the UTF-8 character set, but I can't find any solution in the Dart language. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no built-in converter for *ISO-8859-2* in [dart:convert](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_convert.html). So you have to implement your own [codec](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_convert/Codec.html).

You can look at the code of [Latin1Codec](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_convert/Latin1Codec.html) to implement a `Latin2Codec`. Once ready you will be able to do :

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

final LATIN2 = new Latin2Codec();

main() {
  List<int> bytesForIso_8859_2 = ...;
  List<int> bytesForUTF8 = LATIN2.fuse(UTF8).encode(bytesForIso_8859_2);
}
```